# Preload classes upon app launch

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have an app where on the main view that is initially loaded, it will have an indicator that will show how many items are in a tableview that is in another class. I presume I have to preload the tableview class while the app is launching so the indicator can update correctly, how can I do this?

Comment: how do you plan to access this tableview class, and by tableviewclass do you mean uitableviewcontroller?

Answer (score 0):

What is the table's datasource? I'd say if the data in the table is coming from a plist or other file, you could load the file into an array in the main view's class, be able to get a count from that, and then just reference it from this class when you need it in the tableview class.  But if the datasource is coming from information generated mainly inside the tableview class, then I'd think you'd have to load it all first.

Answer (score 0):

A table view's job is just to be the view that represents some data model. That data model is usually an array of some kind that represents items in database, a plist, somewhere online, etc.

You shouldn't be thinking about invisibly preloading the actual table view here-- that's overkill and breaks the MVC design-- the count of the items is a function of that underlying data model, so just preload the data model (or do whatever you need to do to load the item count).

There are multiple ways to pass around or share a reference to that underlying data model once its loaded, so you can use it from both views, but you'll have to say more about the structure of your app (and probably ask another question) to get good advice on that.